# Codefirst : como agregar funciones desde .NET 6 a postgreSQL utilizando migrations

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net

Quiero agregar una funcion c# a mi base de datos postgresql utilizando migrations, **la funcion no esta creada en mi db**, quiero que se cree al levantar la migracion
¿Alguien pudo o sabe si esto puede hacerse desde visual studio?

```
public static decimal Gethaversineformule (decimal latitude1, decimal latitude2, decimal longitude1, decimal longitude2)
        {
            const double r = 6378100; // earth radious

            var sdlat = Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(latitude2 - latitude1) / 2);
            var sdlon = Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(longitude2 - longitude1) / 2);
            var q = sdlat * sdlat + Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(latitude1)) * Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(latitude2)) * sdlon * sdlon;
            var d = Convert.ToDecimal(2 * r * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(q)));
            return d;
        }
```

esta es la funcion que quiero migrar a mi db

Answer (score 2):

encontré una solución.
se crea una migration vacia y se agrega la funcion como un string mediante el metodo migrationBuilder.Sql()

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql(
                @$"create or replace function {$"\"schema\""}.GetHaversineFormule(latitude1 numeric, latitude2 numeric, longitude1 numeric, longitude2 numeric)
                    returns numeric
                    language plpgsql
                    as
                    $$
                    declare
                     valueReturn numeric;
                                sdlat numeric := sin((latitude2 - latitude1) / 2);
                                sdlon numeric := sin((longitude2 - longitude1) / 2);
                                q numeric;
                                d numeric;
                                begin
                                    q := sdlat * sdlat + cos(latitude1) * cos(latitude2) * sdlon * sdlon;
                            valueReturn:= 2 * 6378100 * asin(sqrt(q));
                                return valueReturn;
                                end; 
                $$; ");

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql($"drop function {$"\"schema\""}.GetHaversineFormule(latitude1 numeric, latitude2 numeric, longitude1 numeric, longitude2 numeric)");
        }
```